# Running 'mvn clean package' in the command line - I cannot see jar file in the eclipse repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, package

I have a **'Main.java'** file.

When I run **'mvn clean package' in the terminal**, it packages the jar file.

However, I cannot see where the .jar file is stored. I believe it should be in the **'target'** folder on my eclipse repository, but it is not there! (see screenshot below)

In the terminal, I **changed the current directory** to: **'/Users/macbook/eclipse-workspace/newestplugin'** before running 'mvn clean package'.

[image]

I would be so grateful for a helping hand as to whether there is a way round this so I can actually find the .jar file?

Comment: Did you try "F5" refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I went through the following steps:

1. I first closed **the eclipse app** on my macbook which I used to create the source code
2. I then **opened the app again**
3. I then clicked on the **'.java' file** and went to the tab **'file'**, and then pressed **'refresh'** to refresh the file
4. The '.jar' file then appeared in **the 'target'** folder, which was located **within the main project folder** on eclipse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community is that ok now? :)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse assumes it is managing the folders.

If you change it outside of eclipse, you have to refresh the view.